# conversion of protocol array to any object in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, casting, swift2

I have a function `storeInCache` that accepts an `AnyObject?`

When I try to give it an optional array of protocol objects it fails with compilation error "`cannot invoke 'storeInCache' with an argument of list of type '([HasImage]?, String)'`". Basically it cannot convert the
[HasImage]? to AnyObject? I believe.

I do not understand this, because the array holds objects (that comply with the HasImage protocol yes), its an array so its an AnyObject no?

I tried different ways of casting but none of them worked.
How can this be solved in swift?

Sample code:

```
protocol HasImage {
    var imageUrl : String? {get}
}


class Product : NSObject, HasImage {
    var imageUrl : String?
    init(imageUrl : String?) {
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
    }
}


func storeInCache(obj : AnyObject?, key : String)
{
    //if no object supplied nothing to store in cache!
    //...
}

func testCaching(addDummyData : Bool) {
    var objectsWithImages : [HasImage]?
    if addDummyData {
    objectsWithImages = [Product(imageUrl: "http://wwww.someserver.com/p1/image.jpg"),Product(imageUrl: "http://wwww.someserver.com/p2/image.jpg")]
    }
    //fails compilation with => cannot invoke 'storeInCache' with an argument of list of type '([HasImage]?, String)'
    storeInCache(objectsWithImages,"somekey")
}
```

Comment: The last line should be `storeInCache(objectsWithImages, key: "somekey")`, correct?

Comment: No apparently it does not need the label, probably because the function is a general function (not a member function of a class).

Comment: If it does not need the label then, I guess, you are using Swift 1.2. I thought you were using Swift 2.0 since you tagged the question with `swift2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add @objc to your protocol declaration and it should be fine,

```
@objc
protocol HasImage {
    var imageUrl : String? {get}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this makes the difference GeneratorOne?

Comment: This trick is magic and weird, It would be great to have a explication on that :D